# Battery drain in Dell 5420 Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dell, power-management, battery

I am using a Dell Latitude 5420 laptop with ubuntu 20.04 for a year. The battery drains out in around an hour or so. Most of the time I have to restart the laptop because power runs out very quickly. I have tried installing tlp, cpufreq, autocpufreq, slimbookbattery, disconnecting bluetooth, adjusting the available settings like brightness etc. However, they have increased the battery life by maybe 20 to 30 minutes at max (slimbookbattery is a bit effective but still unsatisfactory). Can anyone please suggest how to improve the battery life, atleast till 2.5 or 3 hours if possible. Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Replace the battery - not holding a charge is symptomatic of impending failure.

Answer (score 0):

Battery status is fine. I think it was some issue related to ubuntu 20.04 version. I upgraded to ubuntu 22.04 and it has some inbuilt power management options in settings, which we can choose from. Battery life has improved significantly after that.